# Why can't I use Iterator or Map.get() in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to React here, running into a problem with the Map<> object, for whatever reason, TypeScript/React doesn't like me trying to use the Map.get() or trying to iterate over like this:

```
interface IProps {
  schedule: Map<string, Schedule>
}

const StoreHours = ({ schedule }: IProps) => {
    for(const key in schedule) {
        console.log(key);
        // this line gives me an error 'Uncaught TypeError: schedule.get is not a function'
        //console.log(schedule.get(key));
    }

    for (let [key, value] of schedule) {
        //schedule is not iterable if I uncomment this
        //console.log(value); 
    }
    return (<div>test</div>);
}
export default StoreHours;
```

If I uncomment, I get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: schedule.get is not a function' - or 'scheduleis not iteratable' if I use the for...of - is there any reason I can't seem to use a Map?  Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `for..of` to iterate over a `Map`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: I agree @AlexanderStaroselsky - I tried that too earlier - added to the post (just decided to post when I was trying this way)

Comment: Can you share exactly how `schedule` is created and passed down to `StoreHours`?

Answer (score 1):

> ...is there any reason I can't seem to use a Map?

We cannot iterate with `of` over `Map` when we are targeting `es5` in our `tsconfig.json` file.

> TypeScript is a syntactic superset of JavaScript, not a functional superset. When syntax and functionality intersect, there is a bit of a grey area. **When targeting ES5, TypeScript assumes that only number indexed based objects (ArrayLike) can be down-emitted with for ... of** because those are only the functional structures which are guaranteed to be supported by ES5. [emphasis added]

Here are three options. The last one is the simplest for apps that run in a web browser.

- target `es6`
- use `babel`
- set `"downlevelIteration": true` in `tsconfig.json`

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6842